# Which sentence is more appropriate

Tags: usage, possessives

Is there any difference between these two sentences? Which is the appropriate sentence to use?

1. **A student misbehaving with his teachers is so disrespectful**.
2. **A student's misbehaving with his teachers is so disrespectful**.

What if I pick 'a student' as the headword of the first sentence ? Can I not say that 'a student'is the subject and 'misbehaving'is a participle describing 'a student'?

Answer (score 0):

Either is correct. Though, as the comment by Lambie indicates, they are both kind of awkward.

The meaning of each is slightly different.  Number 1 is indicating that the student is indecent. Number 2 is indicating the behavior is indecent.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Your answer contradicts to https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/320111/158559. Please have a look.

Comment: @SahilLaskar Updating a question in a way that invalidates an answer is quite rude. The question you refer to does not contradict my answer.